# Getting error msg "the method asList(string[]) is undefined for the type arrays"

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections

```
import java.util.*;

public class ZCollMethods {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] animals = {"dog", "cat", "mouse", "goat"};
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(animals);
```

The above line gives an error msg

```
the method asList(string[]) is undefined for the type arrays
```

Someone please help. I am only a beginner and I cant proceed further.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: in Java 8 it will work fine..

Comment: how do you say Arrays its own class @Reimeus . You can see the imports man

Comment: @VikrantKashyap In Java 7 also, it works.

Comment: Check your java version, it may be before Java 5

Comment: Check your Java Compiler settings in the Project's Properties. JDK Compliance may be pointing to 1.5. Change that to the latest.

Comment: The version is java 1.8 and the Compiler Compliance level is set at 1.8

Comment: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2). This is what it reads.

Answer (score 1):

**Either** change this line of Code

```
 List<String> list = Arrays.asList(animals);
```

with `List<String> list = java.util.Arrays.asList(animals);`    **OR**

change your global import statement `java.util.*`to specific `java.util.Arrays` may resolve Your Problem.

Comment: i tried changing the code, it's still the same @Rg90 The version is java 1.8 and the Compiler Compliance level is set at 1.8

Answer (score 0):

For InellijIdea

**File - Settings**

```
Build, Execution, Deployment - Compiler - Java Compiler
```

Set 1.8 for

```
- Project bytecode version
- For each module in "Per-module bytecode version"
```

**File - Project Structure - Modules**

Set 1.8 for

```
Language level in each module
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you imported the correct 'Arrays'

import java.util.Arrays;

Answer (score 0):

use this instead:

```
List<String> nameArrayList = List.of(name);
```